# Conditional registry change based on architecture

Tags: inno-setup, registrykey, pascalscript

I should need your precious help with Inno Setup (be patient as I am not a programmer).

I have been asked to provide a script that performs (only in Windows 10) certain registry changes after the installation of `myprogram.exe`.

In all other operating system different from Windows 10 setup just runs `myprogram.exe` and performs no checks.

In Windows 10 after the installation of `myprogram.exe` I should have (in x64 versions) two registry keys being changed.

The registry keys I should change after “myprogram.exe” installation are:

In 64-bit versions:

- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feature Control\FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE`
- `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feature Control\ FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE`

In 32-bit versions:

- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feature Control\FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE`

By adding a dword (in the above keys) called `myprogram.exe` with the hexadecimal value `$7BF`

I tried to add `[Code]` section and `MinVersion:` at the end of each `RegWriteDwordValue` statements.

I do not know how to differentiate keys to be modified from 32- and 64-bit versions and how to create the dword with the hex value `$7BF`.

So far this is my listing:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "C:\Meleena\myprogram.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: "C:\Meleena\myprogram.exe";

[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if IsWin64 and if CurStep = sspostInstall then begin
    RegWritedwordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feature Control\ FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE\',
      'Myprogram.exe', $7BF); Minversion:10.0.10240
    RegWritedwordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feature Control\ FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE\',
      'Myprogram.exe', $7BF); Minversion:10.0.10240
  end;
  if IsnotWin64 and if CurStep = sspostInstall then begin
    RegWritedwordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feature Control\ FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE\',
      'Myprogram.exe', $7BF); Minversion:10.0.10240
  end;  
end;
```

May you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a Pascal Scripting for this. Inno Setup allows this natively. You just need to allow the setup to run in [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

```
[Setup]
; Allow 64-bit mode
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Registry]
; Both 32-bit and 64-bit
Root: HKLM; \
    Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE"; \
    ValueType: dword; ValueName: "myprogram.exe"; ValueData: $7BF; MinVersion:10.0.10240

; On 64-bit systems, install also to Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\...
; Note the HKLM32
Root: HKLM32; \
    Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DOCUMENT_COMPATIBLE_MODE"; \
    ValueType: dword; ValueName: "myprogram.exe"; ValueData: $7BF; MinVersion:10.0.10240; \
    Check: IsWin64
```

---

Note that it's `FeatureControl`, not `Feature Control`.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin.This is what I needed.